# How to increase or decrease size of a matrix in Java?

Tags: java

I have m×n matrix and I need to change the number of columns (increase or decrease). I have the following code but it does not work.

```
public class Resize {

    public static int [][] A = new int [2][2];
    public static int i, j;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A = (int[][])resizeArray(A,4);
        for(i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++){
        for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
            A[i][j] = j+i;
            System.out.print(A[i][j]+"   ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
// resize arr from dimension n = 20 to dimension n = 14  ///////////////
private static Object resizeArray (Object oldArray, int newSize) {
       int oldSize = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(oldArray);
       Class elementType = oldArray.getClass().getComponentType();
       Object newArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(elementType, newSize);
       int preserveLength = Math.min(oldSize, newSize);
       if (preserveLength > 0)
          System.arraycopy(oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, preserveLength);
       return newArray; 
    }
}
```

Comment: "does not work" is not a working problem description. Beyond that : arrays can't be resized. You can only create a completely new array and assign that to an existing array, effectively discarding the first array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing the number of rows rather than the number of columns in your `resizeArray` method. You can tell by printing at the end of your main method, `A.length`, which equals the number of rows in the 2D array. The line

```
int oldSize = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(oldArray);
```

is the same as setting `oldSize` to `A.length`. So we both agree that `oldSize` is the number of rows in the inputted array. And then the line

```
System.arraycopy(oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, preserveLength);
```

copies elements `oldArray[0]`, `oldArray[1]`, `oldArray[2]`, ... `oldArray[preserveLength - 1]` to `newArray[0]`, `newArray[1]`, `newArray[2]`, ... `newArray[preserveLength - 1]` respectively. With a 2D array, you're basically copying rows of the old array and putting them into a new array.

A possible solution could be to make a new array of size `Math.min(oldArray[0].length, newLength)` and then loop through the new array by putting elements from the old array into the new array.

```
private static int[][] resizeArray (int[][] oldArray, int newSize) {
   int oldSize = oldArray[0].length; //number of columns
   int preserveLength = Math.min(oldSize, newSize);
   int[][] newArray = new int[oldArray.length][newSize];
   for(int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < preserveLength; j++) {
           newArray[i][j] = oldArray[i][j];
       }
   } 
   return newArray;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign it to array A as it's dimensions are already defined. You can declare another array which is not initiated.

Also I think you are making it too much complicated in resizeArray method. unless you want to learn reflection you can just create a new array with new size then copy and return;